# Show that if $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq A $ then $ \mathcal{P}(A) \in A $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was working on a revision worksheet and I came across this question, and I was not sure to answer it. Can anyone help me out with this? Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $ \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq A $, then $ \mathcal{P}(A) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq A $, because $ \mathcal{P}(A) $ is a subset of $ A $ and hence an element of $ \mathcal{P}(A) $. Therefore, $ \mathcal{P}(A) \in A $.

**Note:** The Axiom of Regularity is necessarily violated here (thanks, Trevor, for pointing out the need to rephrase).

Comment: From a purely formal point of view I understand your answer; nevertheless, the problem is highly counter-intuitive. Could you please produce an explicit example of such set?

Comment: @Alex: This doesn’t happen in $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ because it violates the Axiom of Regularity. I guess the OP was requesting for a purely formal argument.

Comment: I don't see how the axiom of regularity is relevant; can't we always diagonalize to get a subset of $A$ that is not an element of $A$? (I am not the downvoter, by the way.)

Comment: @Trevor: Hi Trevor. Yes, of course. All I’m saying is that if we assume that $ \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq A $, then it contradicts our assumption that a set cannot be an element of itself.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by "violating the Axiom of Regularity is necessary here".  Indeed, it is necessary for the Axiom of Regularity to fail in order for the implication the OP is asking about to be non-vacuous.  (My comment amounts to saying that it is also necessary for the Axiom of Separation to fail in order for the implication to be non-vacuous.)

Comment: @Trevor: By the way, Trevor, don’t worry about that ephemeral downvote. I’m used to being in a sea of anonymous downvoters.

Comment: It's interesting to know, but it is generally consistent with $\sf ZF-Reg$ that there is some set $A$ for which $\mathcal P(A)\in A$. Of course, $\mathcal P(A)\nsubseteq A$ since Cantor's theorem is provable without appealing to Regularity.

Answer (score 9):

A falsity implies anything. And the condition is *always* false.

Due to Cantor's theorem, $|\mathcal{P}(S)| > |S|$ always. But $\mathcal{P}(S) \subseteq S$ implies $|\mathcal{P}(S)| \leq |S|$ (which is false!), and a falsity implies literally [everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), including $\mathcal{P}(S) \in S$.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that this is an especially simple instance of Cantor's theorem (which can also be seen as a version of Russell's paradox) because the set to consider is just $\{x \in S : x \notin x\}$.